# perl + return code 1 from perl script

Tags: perl

in my little perl script (test.pl) I do the following in order to exit from program if
EXIT_STATUS equal to 1

```
   if ( $EXIT_STATUS  == 1  )
       {
            system (exit);
      }
```

but I need also to get from the test.pl return code 1

for example

./test.pl

echo $?

how to enable return code 1 if EXIT_STATUS = 1 ?

lidia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how you should exit in perl. It's:

```
if ($EXIT_STATUS == 1) {
    exit 1;
}
```

and if you want to exit normally otherwise:

```
if ($EXIT_STATUS == 1) {
    exit 1;
}
else {
    exit 0;
}
```

or (depending on your intention) more simply:

```
exit $EXIT_STATUS;
```

see: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html